# call boost io_service poll in a loop

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-thread

I am currently trying to use boost::asio to update manually a part of my program from a loop like this:

```
class A
{
   A::A() : m_io() {}

   A::update()
   {
     m_io.poll();
     //do other stuff
   }

   A::postSomething()
   {
     while(1)
     {
       m_io.post(...);
       sleep(1000);
     }
   }
}

void main()
{
  A a;

  boost::thread thr(boost::bind(&A::postSomething, &a));

  while(1)
  {
    a.update();
  }
}
```

If I run the program, no post() is processed. However, if I add m_io.reset() in the class member update() like this:

```
A::update()
{
  m_io.poll();
  //do other stuff
  m_io.reset();
}
```

This seems to work, but I am still wondering if it is correct to do this??? Do I risk losing post() calls because of reset()?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say, "no post() is processed", do you mean that you call `post`, then you call `poll`, and not a single item of posted work is done in that call to `poll`?

Comment: Yes, that's it, the post callback is not called after calling poll.

Comment: Can you produce a complete, compilable, minimal test case that you think demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I just can reproduce the problem on Linux. It works on Windows. I will try to produce you a minimal test case. The boost documentation says "The function reset() must be called prior to any second or later set of invocations of the run(), run_one(), poll() or poll_one() functions when a previous invocation of these functions returned due to the io_service being stopped or running out of work." What do you think about this ? Thx

Comment: You should construct a [work](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html) object to keep the io_service alive.

Comment: Yes, it works with work object but I have to use a main loop for my program. Can you tell me what do you think about the boost doumentation http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html. According to the documentation, I think it's normal to use reset(), No ?

Comment: I don't think it's normal to use `reset` because of the requirement that there be no waiting work at the time. Though it's fine to use it if it's between two well-separated tasks that, for some reason, use the same io_service.

Comment: What do you expect [`sleep(1000)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a demo of how to use the work object indeed: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52c2a996a78bb347)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

class A
{
    using ios = boost::asio::io_service;

    ios                        m_io;
    boost::optional<ios::work> m_active;
  public:
    A() : m_io(), m_active(ios::work(m_io)) {}

    ~A() {
        m_active.reset();
        m_io.run(); // to completion
    }

    void update()
    {
        m_io.poll();
        //do other stuff
    }

    void postSomething()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(m_active)
        {
            m_io.post([&]{std::cout<<"something" << ++i << "\n";});
            boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(250));
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    boost::thread thr;
    {
        A a;

        thr = boost::thread(boost::bind(&A::postSomething, &a));

        for (int i = 0; i < 300; ++i)
        {
            boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(5));
            a.update();
        }
    }

    thr.join(); // thread will not join unless A is destructed (m_active is cleared)
}
```

However, you might also want to look at **[Developing Boost Asio Extensions](http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/asio.html#asio_extensions)** as this will allow you to "just `run()`" and still interleave your own (presumably non-IO) tasks

Comment: Indeed, with this example, I understand that I need a worker. Without worker, it doesn't work. Thanks sehe and David Schwartz.

Comment: Wow. Much poet. Such wise :) _(I guess you meant `work` object with 'worker' - the latter is usually used to indicate a background thread)_